# Three.js r60 Height Map

Tags: three.js, revision, heightmap

So I have a heightmap system which works well enough, however since the THREE.js has updated to r60 which removed the Face4 object, I am having issues.

My code is something like this:

```
this.buildGeometry = function(){

  var geo, len, i, f, y;

  geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3000, 3000, 128, 128);
  geo.dynamic = true;
  geo.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-Math.PI / 2));

  this.getHeightData('heightmap.png', function (data) {

    len = geo.faces.length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){

        f = geo.faces[i];
        if( f ){

            y = (data[i].r + data[i].g + data[i].b) / 2;

            geo.vertices[f.a].y = y;
            geo.vertices[f.b].y = y;
            geo.vertices[f.c].y = y;
            geo.vertices[f.d].y = y;

        }

    }

    geo.computeFaceNormals();
    geo.computeCentroids();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000}) );

    scene.add(mesh);

  });
```

};

This works well since a pixel represents each face. How is this done now that the faces are all triangulated?

Similarly I use image maps for model positioning as well. Each pixel matches to the respective Face4 and a desired mesh is placed at its centroid. How can this be accomplished now?

I really miss being able to update the library and do not want to be stuck in r59 anymore =[

Comment: Well at least I feel better since no one else knows how to do this either apparently lol.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works fine on the recent versions (tested on r66).

Notice that the genFn returns the height y given current col and row, maxCol and maxRow (for testing purposes, you can of course replace it with a proper array lookup or from a grayscale image... 64x64 determines the mesh resolution and 1x1 the real world dimensions.

```
var genFn = function(x, y, X, Y) {
    var dx = x/X;
    var dy = y/Y;
    return (Math.sin(dx*15) + Math.cos(dy * 5) ) * 0.05 + 0.025;
};

var geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 64, 64);
geo.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-Math.PI / 2));

var iz, ix,
gridZ1 = geo.widthSegments +1,
gridX1 = geo.heightSegments+1;
for (iz = 0; iz < gridZ1; ++iz) {
    for (ix = 0; ix < gridX1; ++ix) {
        geo.vertices[ ix  + gridX1*iz ].y = genFn(ix, iz, gridX1, gridZ1);
     }
}
geo.computeFaceNormals();
geo.computeVertexNormals();
geo.computeCentroids();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    geo,
    mtl
);

scene.add(mesh);
```